# Liferay URL without language ID

Tags: liferay

I use Liferay and have created a portlet but my site is accessible under two URLS:

1) 10.10.30.30/en/portal

2) 10.10.30.30/portal

But I want my site be always available with this URL without language_ID "EN": 10.10.30.30/portal

Thanx in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Goto *Liferay home* eg. `liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga4/`

Create `portal-ext.properties` file and add the following line:

```
locale.prepend.friendly.url.style=0
```

Restart the server.

Comment: "read the documentation" is missing ;-) : [How to configure time zones and locales](https://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Configure+time+zones+and+locale)

Comment: You can set time zone and locales also as given below. goto control panel--> portal settings --> display settings

Comment: locale.prepend.friendly.url.style=0 doesn't work for Liferay Portal Community Edition 6.0.5 CE (Bunyan / Build 6005 / August 16, 2010)  same as described here https://community.liferay.com/fr/forums/-/message_boards/message/65308903  looks like because ot bug https://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-42001

Comment: workaround if locale.prepend.friendly.url.style=0 doesn't work is described here http://srikanthvelugoti.blogspot.com/2015/05/remove-locale-appending-in-url-liferay.html   >>We need to add the rewrite rule in urlrewrite.xml file which is available under WEB-INF folder of server .
    
            ^(.*)/web/pages$
            /web/pages$

Answer (score 0):

Setting up in portal-ext.xml

locale.prepend.friendly.url.style=0

More info: https://docs.liferay.com/ce/portal/7.1-latest/propertiesdoc/portal.properties.html#Languages%20and%20Time%20Zones